# Selenium Webdrive object retains page source from previous page (of CRM). But page url is current

Tags: chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am writing automation scripts for Dynamics 365 using Selenium Webdriver with C#.
All is good till I login and visit first page (a list).
Test script clicks on one item in first page and page navigates to another page (ok)
Now, when I try to read any field in next page I cannot. 
I found that

> ```
> string pageSource = driver.PageSource; // returns source from previous page,
> string pageUrl = driver.Url; // returns correct/current url of the browser.
> ```

As mentioned in 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/24979/34538
I have waited enough for the page to be loaded completely before accessing it.

To add:
I tested by accessing an object in previous page which is not in current page. And I could read and click it.

Comment: Can you run "document.documentElement.outerHTML"  on the browser console after reaching the desired page and check if this gives you the desired result.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I got the html content that I expect. But I did not get any of the fields, rather I got html code related to menus and status bar only. 

I can use developer toolbar though.
Just trying to understand what purpose does "document.documentElement.outerHTML" solve.

Comment: The getPageSource returns the string serialization of the DOM of the current browsing context. This is internally implemented by calling "document.documentElement.outerHTML" on the page. In this case I would suggest talk to the dev team why you are not getting the entire DOM when calling the "document.documentElement.outerHTML".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing the page source, I refreshed the driver.

```
driver.Navigate().Refresh();
```

This refreshes the DOM element too, (I guess).

Comment: Have you solved your issue with this solution?

Comment: Yes @AlexeyR. This solution solved the issue. Thanks.